# How to remove the directory .t2d on C-c C-c Clean / M-x TeX-clean?

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, auctex

I use the following code in `.emacs` to clean the working directory from
unwanted files.

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(progn
     (setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (delete "\\.synctex\\.gz" LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes))
     (setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (append
                          LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes
                          (list "\\.bcf" "\\.synctex\\.gz(busy)" "-blx\\.bib" "\\.run\\.xml" "\\.fdb_latexmk" "\\.fls" "\\.ptc")))
     (setq LaTeX-clean-output-suffixes (append LaTeX-clean-output-suffixes (list "\\.synctex\\.gz")))
))
```

If my LaTeX document contains an error, the current directory contains a folder
`.t2d` (I compile with `texi2dvi -p` from within Emacs/AUCTeX). I have to
manually switch to the working directory to remove this folder as, otherwise,
the document would not compile (in fact, compilation would stop with the same
error [in most of the cases]). The idea is therefore to include `\\.t2d` in the
above list of files being removed on `C-c C-c Clean`. However, if I do so, `C-c
C-c Clean` says `TeX-clean: Removing old name: is a directory: qrm.t2d`. How can
*directories* be removed on `C-c C-c Clean`?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but typically you need to remove any files and subdirectories in a directory before you can remove the directory itself.  Similarly, for removing those subdirectories: remove their contents first, and so on.

Comment: I do not believe that cleaning normally includes removal of directories or sub-directories.  I think you'll need a separate removal function.  Something like a shell command or start-process that uses something like `rm -rf *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint from lawlist's comment brought the solution. I first discovered that `texi2dvi --mostly-clean` already cleans a lot (including the unwanted directory `.t2d`). I then simply used a `rm` to remove further unwanted files -- everything wrapped so that I can call it via `C-c C-c tidy`:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     ;; texi2dvi
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("texi2dvi" "PDFLATEX='pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error' texi2dvi --max-iterations=5 -p %s.tex" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run texi2dvi") t)
     ;; clean
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("tidy" "texi2dvi --mostly-clean %s.tex; rm %s.pdf \"%s.synctex.gz(busy)\"" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run clean") t)
     ;; default
     (setq TeX-command-default "texi2dvi")))
```